# In Python: Converting EPS files to PNG with alpha channel and no antialiasing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, ghostscript, imagemagick-convert

The title states the requirements, the reality bites.

*Imagemagick*: the results are fine, but it's sloooow. Main reason for exclusion is, there is no current version 7 available for apt-managed packages for our Ubuntu servers.

*Pillow*: Can read EPS, but ignores alpha channel information. Always creates white backgrounds. As it uses ghostscript internally to convert .eps, tried to use it directly.

*Ghostscript*: Closest so far. But it's not possible to switch off antialiasing, which we need to switch off as the results will be used in print.

This is the closest to the desired result I got:

```
gs -dSAFER \
  -dBATCH \
  -dNOPAUSE \
  -dNOPROMPT \
  -dMaxBitmap=500000000 \
  -dEPSCrop \
  -dAlignToPixels=0 \
  -dGridFitTT=2 \
  -sDEVICE=pngalpha \
  -sPAPERSIZE=a7 \
  -r"140x140" \
  -dTextAlphaBits=1 \
  -dGraphicsAlphaBits=1 \
  -sOUTPUTFILE=output.png \
  input.eps
```

But there are still some grayscale pixels next to solid white lines.

Do you know any other sane path to get from .eps to .png files with transparent backgrounds in Python?

Comment: Please share a suitable sample image. Thank you.

Comment: EPS doesn't have alpha channel information, so nothing is "ignoring it". AFAIK, "-dTextAlphaBits=1 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=1" disables interpolation in Ghostscript. Maybe you also need to specify "-dNOINTERPOLATE" to ignore the interpolation request for sampled images